# OpenCV 3.4.2 VideoCapture letter boxed

Tags: python, windows, opencv

I'm using opencv on Windows. When I was using 3.4.1 I was able to capture full HD images and half HD images. After updating to 3.4.2 the image is now letter boxed. The resolution is correct, but there are black bars where there used to be image data. How can I get rid of this letter box?

Here is my capture code:

```py
import cv2
import json

scaleFactor = 1
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, int(1920*scaleFactor))
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, int(1080*scaleFactor))

print cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
print cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        continue

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The print statement out put is

```
1920.0
1080.0
```

And this is a picture of the output

[image: Letter boxed image]

Comment: What do the `print` statements output? How come you get an image on your screen from that code?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this for myself by changing `apiPreference` in [`cv::VideoCapture(index, apiPreference)`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#ad890d4783ff81f53036380bd89dd31aa) from [`cv::CAP_ANY`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#ga023786be1ee68a9105bf2e48c700294d) to [`cv::CAP_DSHOW`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#ga023786be1ee68a9105bf2e48c700294d).

So, in your case:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(2, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
```